# How to type hint dictionary for pandas pd.DataFrame.from_dict()?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, type-hinting, mypy

I am stuck trying to write a type hint for a dictionary for pandas `pd.DataFrame.from_dict()` function.

I am currently on python 3.11.0.

Relevant module versions:

- pandas 1.5.1
- pandas-stubs 1.2.0.62
- mypy 0.982

With the following code: (taken from the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html)).

```
from typing import Dict

import pandas as pd

data: Dict[str, list[int | str]] = {"col_1": [3, 2, 1, 0], "col_2": ["a", "b", "c", "d"]}
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

I get this error from mypy `Argument 1 to "from_dict" of "DataFrame" has incompatible type "Dict[str, List[Union[int, str]]]"; expected "Dict[Union[Optional[Hashable], Union[int, str]], Union[Union[Union[ExtensionArray, ndarray[Any, Any]], Index, Series], Iterable[Any], Dict[Union[Optional[Hashable], Union[int, str]], Any]]]"`

I dont see what I am missing in the typehint?

I expect to get no error from mypy.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why you're getting the error, but it runs for me when I make a few small changes:

```
from typing import Dict, Union, List

data = Dict[str, List[Union[int, str]]]
data = {"col_1": [3, 2, 1, 0], "col_2": ["a", "b", "c", "d"]}
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

Comment: Your code doesn't use type hinting. It just defines `data` twice.

Comment: I see that now - my answer was a long time ago. I thought I was defining `data` as the type and then assigning it, but that's clearly not what's happening. How would I do this correctly?